# How does bash script command substitution work?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, directory

And:  "Why does this particular script have this outcome?"

From [Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in), based on some code snippets offered by user l0b0 in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in#comment16925670_59895) on that question, I used the following for a cron job:

```
DIR=$(pwd)
if [ $CRON == "true" ]; then
  # If the environment variable $CRON is set to true, we're probably in a cron job
  if [ $PWD == "/" ]; then
    # And if the current working directory is root, we're probably in a cron job
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd && echo x)"
    DIR="${DIR%x}"
  fi
fi
```

However, my directory variable ($DIR) somehow ends up with a newline after it anyway, which breaks the script any time the $DIR variable is used to create a path.  Why is the newline there?

Admittedly, I'm not overly familiar with the nuances of bash scripting and command substitution.  It is possible I misunderstood the purpose behind l0b0's script.

Comment: What happens when you change `echo x` to `echo -n`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics echo -n seems to work, but so does omitting the echo x and subsequent substitution entirely.  I'd like to know why the code does what it does.  My understanding of the script was that it preserved directory names that _did_ contain newlines, not add them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: the suggested code is wrong and always adds a line feed (because pwd always prints one).

The corrected version would be

```
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && printf "%sx" "$PWD")"
dir=${dir%x}
```

Comment: It's probably necessary that `pwd` is used over `$PWD`. Wasn't it?

Comment: @theotherguy Well I'm not sure either but just wonder why most folks from the thread don't bother about using it. I was hoping you have an idea since you gave a different answer. I also don't want to examine their difference.

Comment: @konsolebox Reading the comments, it looks like they were just not aware of `$PWD`.

Comment: @theotherguy I actually remember having a case in Cygwin when my project [Shell Script Loader](http://loader.sourceforge.net) was still in its early stages. I was surprised to see how my scripts failed. The reason on it probably was that `pwd` was giving a different output from `$PWD` (both give valid references to a single target, but give different presentations probably as different links). I examined my scripts and some parts of those refer to checking the difference of two methods. Well this might be a rare case for a real Linux system, although I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: As far as I can tell, depending on the system and the implementation of `pwd`, the output of `pwd` and `$PWD` can differ.  The difference seems to usually be in whether or not you get a resolved path (no symlinks) or the path the user/script used to get to the file (possibly symlinks in path).  I don't know if that's why they used `pwd` over `$PWD` in the other question thread.